# "Me neither" or "Me too"?

Tags: phrase-usage

A couple of days ago I had a conversation with the other person telling me a statement like "I'm less interested in..." and my reply to that was "Me neither" - should I have said "Me too"?

Can I use the phrase "me too" for a negative statement ?

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26239/agreement-with-so-and-neither

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's see these examples

A - I am less interested in football.
B - Me too

A - I am not interested in football.
B - Me neither.

A - I am very interested in football.
B - Me too

I don't think the first statement is exactly a negative statement, though it does sound like that. Because there is no negative word in it. So the response 'me neither' is not possible.

However in second sentence there is a negative word. So the response should be 'me neither'.

Third sentence is a positive one. So there is no question of responding it with 'me neither'.

Comment: Also possible: So am/do I. Or: Neither am/do I.