# "me too" Vs "Me either"

Tags: word-choice

Can some explain whats the difference between the two in this context?

```
Person A: I wish I had that car.
Person B: Me too

VS

Person A: I wish I had that car.
Person B: Me either
```

Comment: @cardinal if neither and either mean the same thing, then yes its a duplicate. now the question is, do they mean the same?

Comment: When not used in a pair ("either this or that"), "either" is a [negative polarity item](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item), so it is used only with negatives and questions, not positive statements. So "me either." is not grammatical. In a question "Aren't you coming either?" or a negative "I'm not coming either", it is fine (but if the "not" is not expressed it takes the form "neither": "Me neither").

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Me neither" or "Me too"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/me-neither-or-me-too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to say it in the declarative form:

Person A: I wish I had that car.

Person B: **Me, too**.

VERSUS

Person A: I wish I had that car.
Person B: **So do I**.

Two ways to say it in the negative form.

Person A: I do not like soup for dinner.

Person B: **Neither [or nor] do I**.

OR
Person B: **Me either.** [less formal]

***Either*** **can only be used in response to a NEGATIVE verb in the first sentence**.

Answer (score 1):

"Me too" is correct. *Either* always introduces a pair of alternatives - *Either* X *or* Y. However, *neither* is probably OK to use:

- Person A: I wouldn't buy that car.
- Person B: Me neither.